# Copy unformatted value of cell via macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an Excel Sheet with a text generator, based upon certain circumstances.

The text generated is based on parameters, and is gathered into paragraphs of text in a single cell, using the *CONCATENATE* function.

If I copy the finished contents of the cell into a HTML based editor, such as an e-mail - It copies the formatting and a table (TD).

Is there a way, to copy the text (values only) into clipboard?

I have found solutions to paste it unformatted into a cell in Excel, using the following Visual Basic Code:

```
Sub Copy()

Sheet1.Range("GeneratedText").Copy
Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Copy

End Sub
```

This copies and pastes the text unformatted to the new Cell within Excel - But I wish to paste it elsewhere, and therefor having it stores without formatting in the Clipboard.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you get the unformated value back so after `Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` you do `noFormat = Sheet2.Cells(1,1).Copy`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
Sub CopyValToClipboard()

  val = Sheet1.Range("GeneratedText") // Here, the val contains unformatted value of cell

  With New MSForms.DataObject
    .SetText val
    .PutInClipboard
  End With 

  Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).value = val

End Sub
```

If you can't find Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object library in the list of references, then browse & add a reference to FM20.dll:

[image]

It will start showing immediately:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Will that put the text into Clipboard, unformatted?

Comment: Will that put the text into Clipboard, unformatted? It looks like it would paste the information unformatted to the other sheet unformatted, but would it be saved in the clipboard unformatted?

I get the following error when trying it out:
    Compile error: Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object

Comment: I think Val needs to be defined as:

    Dim Val As New DataObject

And in order for that to function you need to add a Reference (Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library) which I cannot find in the Mac-version of Excel.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Klingan Yes! you got it right. I've updated the answer for putting the value in to ClipBoard, you might wanna check it.

Comment: I ended up using the code below, which ended up working. The issue is that I am running Excel on a Mac, and the FM20.dll file (which I found out I needed through Google) does not seem to exist. The Excel-file was initially created at my workplace, using a Windows PC. No matter what I did, I could not find, add nor browse the _Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library_.

Comment: What I ended up doing, was to create a completely new Excel document, and added some text blocks, radio buttons etc, and a UserForm to the VBA code. After that, the Reference was available in my other Excel (original) document, and the code below worked. Is there any difference between the code you posted and the one I am using below? And question 2.) Can I now send this back to my workplace, in an Windows environment (with restricted access) - and the reference will still be in my Excel sheet?

Comment: `Sub CopyNote()`

Dim val As New DataObject

val.SetText Sheet5.Range("AlertNote").Value
val.PutInClipboard

MsgBox "The generated note has been copied to the clipboard."

End Sub`

Comment: NO, there's nothing different in both of the codes. And, when you add a UserForm, it automatically imports the reference to **MSForms** library which contains **DataObject**, this is why you didn't require to add it manually after using UserForm. Yes, it should work in Windows Environment.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sunny. Although it did not work the first time I added a UserForm (I read this tip online). I had to create a new spreadsheet, make the userform there (and all of a sudden the reference was available to use), and then add a userform to my original sheet - and it would work. Perhaps it has something to do with the original document being created on Windows, what do I know. So if I send this back to my employer, the reference should be there - even though the "pointer" to the reference is not a FM20.dll-file on Mac? :)